# Hide certain named ranges in another worksheet based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code to hide named ranges in another worksheet based on a condition.

I have a worksheet called "Committed Costs":
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDEw1.png)

There will be many more lines at the bottom (I have a little over 7000 right now). Range A3:E14 is named cc_0101, range A14:E26 is named cc_0195. And there are many more below.

I have a "Settings" worksheet:
[image]

Column C is a drop-down with two options: "Show" and "Hide". The formula in column D shows 1 if "Hide" is selected and 0 if "Show" is selected. Now I want the macro to go through the list of accounts on the "Settings" worksheet and if D8=1, then the whole cc_0101 named range from "Committed Costs" worksheet should be hidden, if D9=0, then cc_0195 should not be hidden and so forth. So basically, the macro now has to grab the value from column E for each row.

I have the following code:

```
Dim showhide1 As Range
Set showhide1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("d7:g716")
Dim showhide2 As Variant
showhide2 = showhide1.Value
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = LBound(showhide2, 1) To UBound(showhide2, 1)
  For j = LBound(showhide2, 2) To UBound(showhide2, 2)
    If showhide1(i, 1) = 1 Then
      Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("showhide2(i,2)").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
      Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("showhide2(i,2)").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
  Next j
Next i
```

The code produces

> Run-time error 1004.

Before I started reading about arrays and everything the code looked as follows:

```
Dim drng As Range, d as Range
Dim erng As Range, e as Range

Set drng = Range("D7:D716")
Set erng = Range("E7:E716")

For Each d In drng
  If d = 1 Then
    Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("e").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Else
    Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("e").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If
Next d
```

Then I realized that I am not defining "e" in any way, so the macro won't know to grab the value from column E (I am guessing). The only way I got the condition to work was:

```
Dim d as Range
Set d = Range("D8")

If d = 1 Then
  Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("cc_0101").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
  Sheets("Committed Costs").Range("cc_0101").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

but that doesn't serve the purpose. I have to hard-code the name of the range, which is cc_0101 in the example and the code only compares one line (row 8), instead of going through the whole list of accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix, it is around how you reference your array items. Also, there is no need to loop through your column indexes as they are never used. Change your code to the below. why you pass the array values as `"showhide2(i,2)"` it is looking for a sheet titled "showhide2(i,2)", as opposed to the value stored in `showhide2(i,2)`.

```
Dim showhide1 As Range
Set showhide1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("d7:g716")
Dim showhide2 As Variant
showhide2 = showhide1.Value
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = LBound(showhide2, 1) To UBound(showhide2, 1)
     If showhide2(i, 1) = 1 Then
         Sheets("Committed Costs").Range(showhide2(i,2)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Else
         Sheets("Committed Costs").Range(showhide2(i,2)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
Next i
```

Comment: I tried to do it the way Kyle suggested, but it results in the same Run-time error 1004. The debugger highlights the following section of the code: "Sheets("Committed Costs").Range(showhide2(i, 2)).EntireRow.Hidden = False"

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, I'll keep it consistent and use showhide2(i,1), but it didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @user3055019 - are all the range names defined in your macro workbook's Settings sheet, in cells E7:E716 defined?  (You will get that error if the cell is empty, or the range name does not exist.)  You may need an extra If statement wrapped around the existing one, i.e. `If showhide1(i, 2) <> "" Then` `If showhide1(i, 1) = 1 Then` ... `End If` `End If`.

Comment: @user3055019 - Oops - change `showhide1` to `showhide2` in my suggested change - I copy/pasted my suggestion from the "inconsistent" version of the code.

Comment: @YowE3K This is beautiful, thank you very much, your solution worked! I did have a few cc_xxxx codes that were not defined on the Committed Costs worksheet. I limited the showhide1 range to include only the ranges with defined names and it worked beautifully! Now I have to define names for the other 500+ sections.